# Using modules that are "unsafe" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

How do you import modules that cause the ghci compiler to fail to compile due to them being safe? I'm trying to use Debug.Trace but I'm being told by the compiler it's unsafe.

Comment: that's odd. what's your error message?

Comment: Do you mean "untrusted"? There is an important difference.

Comment: Does the module you are compiling have a `{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}` pragma at the top? Certainly this can't be followed by `import Debug.Trace`. If not, could it be that `-XSafe` is being used somewhere else, e.g. in the way you are calling ghci? Also, un`Safe`ness is supposed to be recursive, so if you are compiling a module that has `{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}`  but imports the module you are modifying, there will similarly be trouble.

Comment: It had the language safe pragma at the top, didn't realise that. Thanks for the help, @Arthur do you want to submit it as an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Comment: Ah, of course that can close the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the module you are compiling have a `{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}` pragma at the top? Certainly this can't be followed by import `Debug.Trace`. If not, could it be that `-XSafe` is being used somewhere else, e.g. in the way you are calling ghci? Also, un`Safe`ness is supposed to be recursive, so if you are compiling a module that has `{-# LANGUAGE Safe #-}` but imports the module you are modifying, there will similarly be trouble.